# Drag/drop ins Data Grid View -Row and column are always -1

Tags: c#, datagridview, drag-and-drop

I am trying to take text from a list box control and put it into a particular cell in a data Grid.   I am using the following code:

```
    private void DG_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView.HitTestInfo theHit = DG.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        int theCol = theHit.ColumnX;
        int theRow = theHit.RowY;
        MessageBox.Show(theCol.ToString() + " " + theRow.ToString());

    }
```

By the column and row coordinates are always -1.   I suspect the X and Y coming in need to be adjusted somehow, but I am not sure how or if this is the problem.   Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, here is the code in case anyone else has a similar problem:

```
   Point theLoc = DG.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

        DataGridView.HitTestInfo theHit = DG.HitTest(theLoc.X,theLoc.Y);
        int theCol = theHit.ColumnIndex;
        int theRow = theHit.RowIndex;
        MessageBox.Show(theCol.ToString() + " " + theRow.ToString());
```